Create dynamic key from given variables
In my project the code supposed to call bitbucket repos and get all the available branches. My responsibility is create dict where keys will branch name and value will number of child branches.
listOfRepos =         ['repo/association/branch/master','repo/publish/branch/master']
listOfChildBranches = [["childBranch1","childBranch2","childBranch3"], 
                       ["working1","demo2","rebased3"]]

Required output is:
repo/association/branch/master=['childBranch1', 'childBranch2', 'childBranch3']
repo/publish/branch/master=['working1', 'demo2', 'rebased3']


Can you please edit your question to include what you have tried so far to solve the issue? See: How to ask a good question

"My responsibility is create dict" well your "Required output" does not satisfy that requirement

As per your requirement, this code will work.
listOfRepos =         ["repo/association/branch/master","repo/publish/branch/master"]
listOfChildBranches = [["childBranch1","childBranch2","childBranch3"],
                           ["working1","demo2","rebased3"]]
newList = dict()
for i in range(0,len(listOfRepos)):
    newList[listOfRepos[i]] = listOfChildBranches[i]

print(listOfRepos[0]+"="+str(newList["repo/association/branch/master"]))
print(listOfRepos[1]+"="+str(newList["repo/publish/branch/master"]))

To be more dynamic :
for idx,i in enumerate(listOfRepos):
    print(i+"="+str(newList[str(listOfRepos[idx])]))


You can zip your two inputs and then create a dict from the result
>>> dict(zip(listOfRepos, listOfChildBranches))
{
  'repo/association/branch/master': ['childBranch1', 'childBranch2', 'childBranch3'],
  'repo/publish/branch/master': ['working1', 'demo2', 'rebased3']
}

